# cant call this func : TypeError: update_groups() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uids'

Tags: python, odoo, func, odoo-14

i make a module profile to add groups into profile.
when make a new user, we can add profile for user profiles and user will auto authorized groups in profile.
but i cant make user auto add groups from profile.
cant someone help me pls.
thanks a lot.
i had thit error: TypeError: update_groups() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uids'.

There is my code:
profile.py:

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models,fields, api,tools
import string
from odoo.tools.translate import _


class Users(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    
    profile_id = fields.Many2one('res.profiles',string="Profile")

    profiles_ids = fields.Many2many('res.profiles','profile_user_rel','user_id','profile_id', string='Profile Name')
    
    
    def update_groups(self,uids):
        users_pool = self.env["res.profiles"]
        if uids:
            for user in users_pool.browse(uids):
                if not user.profiles_ids and user.id != 2:
                    user.write({'groups_id':[[6,0,[]]]})
                if user.profiles_ids:
                    sql = """UPDATE FROM res_groups_users_rel WHERE uid = %s"""%(user.id)
                    self._cr.execute(sql)
                    groups_ids = []
                    for profile in user.profiles_ids:
                        groups_ids += [x.id for x in profile.groups_ids if x.id not in groups_ids]
                    user.write({'groups_id':[[6,0,groups_ids]]})
        return True
    
    
    
    def update_profile(self):
        self.env["user.profiles"].update_groups(self.ids)
        return True
    
        
class GroupInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.groups'
    
    
    profiles_groups_ids = fields.Many2many('res.profiles','profile_group_rel','group_id','profile_id', string='Profile Name')   




class UserProfile(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.profiles'
    _description = 'Profile Record'
    _rec_name = 'profile_name'
    
    _sql_constraints = [('name_uniq','unique(name)', 'Profile name must be unique!'),]
    _order = "profile_name"

    
    
 
    
    profile_name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    
    
    groups_ids = fields.Many2many('res.groups','profile_group_rel','profile_id','group_id',string='Authorized Group')
    
    
    user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users','profile_user_rel','profile_id','user_id', string='User Name')
    
    ```

 profile.xml:
   
    ```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
     

          
     <!-- tree view -->
     <record id="profile_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">user.profile.tree</field>
            <field name="model">res.profiles</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string= "profile">
                  <field name="profile_name"/>
                  <field name="user_ids"/>
                  <field name="groups_ids"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
     </record>
     
        <!-- view form -->
     <record id="student_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">user.profile.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.profiles</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="Profile">
                <sheet>
                 <div class="oe_title">
                 </div>
                  <group>
                   <group><field name="profile_name"/></group>
                   <group><field name="user_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/></group>
                   <group><field name="groups_ids"/></group>
                   </group>
                </sheet> 
               </form>
            </field>
     </record>
     
     
     <!--action of the student menu-->
     <record id="action_profile" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Profile</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">res.profiles</field>        
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
              <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                Create First profile !
              </p>
            </field>  
     </record>
     

     
         <!-- profile name in group view -->
     <record id="group_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">group.inherit</field>
         <field name="model">res.groups</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_groups_form"></field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <field name="name" position="after">
                 <field name="profiles_groups_ids"/>
             </field>
         </field>
     </record>
     
              <!-- profile name in user view -->
     <record id="user_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">user.inherit</field>
         <field name="model">res.users</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"></field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <field name="login" position="after">
                 <field name="profiles_ids"/>
             </field>
             <field name="profiles_ids" position="after">
                   <div class='oe_button_box' name="button_box"><button name='update_groups'
                   type="object" class="oe_stat_button" string="update"></button></div> 
             </field>
             <button name="action_show_groups" position="attributes">
                 <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
             </button>
             <field name="groups_count" position="attributes">
                 <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
             </field>
         </field>
     </record> 
     
     <menuitem id="profiles" name="User Profile" parent="base.menu_users" sequence="4" action="action_profile"/>
     <menuitem id="user_root" name="Profile" sequence="0"/>
     <menuitem id="user_profile" name ="Profile" parent="user_root" action="action_profile"/>
   
</odoo>   
    
    
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling it without a recordset (i.e. call it from model directly) as you did by `self.env["user.profiles"].` you should use `@api.model`:

```py
    @api.model
    def update_groups(self,uids):
        users_pool = self.env["res.profiles"]
        #...
```

Other wise it expect an implicit pass of `ids` argument and your `self.ids` goes for this hidden one.

also you have used `"users.profile"` in

````
        self.env["user.profiles"].update_groups(self.ids)```
I think it is a typo.

But why you don't use recordsets?:

```python
    def update_groups(self):
        for user in self:
            if not user.profiles_ids and user.id != 2:
                user.write({'groups_id':[[6,0,[]]]})
            if user.profiles_ids:
                sql = """UPDATE FROM res_groups_users_rel WHERE uid = %s"""%(user.id)
                self._cr.execute(sql)
                groups_ids = []
                for profile in user.profiles_ids:
                    groups_ids += [x.id for x in profile.groups_ids if x.id not in groups_ids]
                user.write({'groups_id':[[6,0,groups_ids]]})
    
    
    
    def update_profile(self):
        self.update_groups()
````

Comment: Can you teach me how to use recordset in this case? It still not working .I am newbie. Thank a lot to spend time to help me